# How is the "cluster creator" user of an AWS EKS cluster mapped to the "system:masters" RBAC group?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubernetes-rbac

I'm trying to understand how are managed RBAC authorizations for the first user that create an EKS cluster within AWS.
Or in other words : How is the cluster creator mapped to the "system:masters" group within RBAC ?

I know this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) states : *"When you create an Amazon EKS cluster, the IAM entity user or role, such as a federated user that creates the cluster, is automatically granted system:masters permissions in the cluster's RBAC configuration."*
And I understand how clusterrole *cluster-admin* and clusterrolebinding *cluster-admin* grants full admin rights to any members of the "system:masters" group.

What I can't figure out is how/where is the cluster creator user mapped to this group ? (the "automatically granted" part of the doc)

*PS: I know that to add additionnal user/roles I'm supposed to use the aws-auth configmap, but this first user is not defined here and still has access to cluster.*

If anyone can enlighten me please ?

Thanks in advance!

For the record I'm using a kubernetes 1.18 EKS cluster that was built with terraform via the community module [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks) :

```
module "cluster" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "13.2.1"

  cluster_version = "1.18"
  cluster_name    = "memorandom-${local.id}"
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnets         = module.vpc.private_subnets

  write_kubeconfig = false
  manage_aws_auth  = true

  worker_groups = [
    {
      instance_type = "t3.medium"
      asg_max_size  = 3
      key_name      = "pbenefice"
    }
  ]

  tags = local.tags
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I reached for AWS Support on this topic. And to summarize the answer was : "*Most of what you are asking about is confidential information and cannot be disclosed.*".

I paste the full reply here :

---

Thanks for reaching out to AWS Premium Support. My name is * and I understand you're curious about the implementation details of the cluster creator's being part of the system:masters group.

Most of what you are asking about is confidential information and cannot be disclosed.

However, I can tell you that the EKS Control Plane has an Authenticator component. You can enable logs for this as described here [1].

Personally, I like to think of that "automatically granted" part of the docs as an imaginary, read-only permanent object under the `mapUsers:` section of the aws-auth configmap. Imaginary because it's not implemented in the aws-auth configmap, but the permissions it is granted are the same as if it were there.  I've created an imaginary cluster-creator user object in the example below [2] that shows the effective implementation

[1]: Amazon EKS control plane logging - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html

[2]: Example aws-auth configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/eksctl-my-cluster-nodegroup-standard-wo-NodeInstanceRole-1WP3NUE3O6UCF
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
  mapUsers: |
    # The way EKS currently bootstraps your cluster permissions, you can think of the cluster-creator having a
    # read-only permanent entry here - the effective permissions are the same
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/cluster-creator
      username: cluster-creator
      groups:
        - system:masters
    # In an actual aws-auth configmap, the cluster-creator entry above isn't there and
    # only the mapUsers below would be shown
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/admin
      username: admin
      groups:
        - system:masters
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/ops-user
      username: ops-user
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

The most important practical considerations regarding the cluster creator RBAC permissions are:

- the IAM entity (user or role) that created the cluster is always going to have admin privileges (system:masters permissions)
- if IAM entity is deleted without other IAM entities being added with the necessary permissions to the aws-auth configmap - you have two options:

  1. you must either recreate the IAM entity with the same name to regain access to your cluster, or
  2. delete the cluster and create a new cluster using a new IAM entity

I know this probably wasn't all the information you'd hoped for, but I hope it helps satisfy part of your curiosity.
As I can't go into any real depth to answer your questions, I'll go ahead and resolve your case.
I hope you have a wonderful day and please feel free to reach out to us anytime.

Comment: How do we know a cluster was created by IAM roles or IAM users?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `aws-auth` `configMap` is not the only source of truth. The initial user is coming from a [MountedFile](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator#mountedfile)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
I think it might be what I'm look for but on the EKS cluster I built I can't see anything related to the deployment of AWS IAM Authenticator...
Therefore I do not understand how it is managed on the AWS side, And I can't find any volumes that would match this MountedFile.
Do you have any idea on how this work on a managed EKS cluster ?
PS: I opened a ticket to AWS, I'm waiting to see if I get more informations from them.

Answer (score 0):

the aws-auth map implementation for IAM - Kubernetes RBAC mapping is done with a control plane deployed dynamic webhook server(admission webhook).

- the cluster creator is mapped in this same webhook config file that is used to authenticate and authorize other requests against the aws-auth map
- the cluster creator is simply not written to the aws-auth map to avoid erroneous edits or changes - `some entity must always have access to the cluster` is the design consideration for this
- although, we may have deleted the IAM cluster creator from the AWS IAM - so the cluster knows the creating entity, but we dont have the entity existing in the AWS account anymore